# mpdf generates a blank pdf file if there is an angle bracket in the source html

Tags: php, mpdf

When the source html has an angle bracket, mpdf generates a blank page. If I remove the angle bracket it works just fine.

An example html which causes the problem is d

I have tried the following and none of it actually helped:

1. `Setting $mpdf->debug = true;` does not produce any error.  But still results a blank page.
2. `$this->m_pdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;`
3. `$this->m_pdf->charset_in = 'UTF-8';`
4. `mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'windows-1252');`

mpdf version is 6.0
php version is 5.4.45

I would not want to upgrade php version as of now and hence would prefer a solution with the same version of mpdf and php.

Comment: What do you mean by an "angle bracket"? A single `<` or `>`?

Comment: Have you tried changing the angle brackets to their equivalent HTML entity `&gt;` or `&lt;`?

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped

Answer (score 0):

Use ***`&lt;`*** for < and ***`&gt;`*** for >

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. The function

```
htmlentities()
```

was used to correct it.